# Downgrade PHP 7.1.7 to PHP 7.0.6 CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, php, centos-7, downgrade

Is it possible to downgrade PHP version from 7.1.7 to 7.0.6 on centOS 7?

I've try to run

```
yum remove php-common php-cli mod-php
```

then install php with run

```
yum -y install php70w-pdo php70w-mysqlnd php70w-opcache php70w-xml php70w-mcrypt php70w-gd
```

but always said php 7.0 is obsolete version will be replace with 7.1

[image: Always return back to php 7.1.7]

Is there any ways to downgrade PHP version, because I need to install Magento 2.1.7 that required php 7.0x version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One always need to safely downgrade the PHP version using the commands.

The following are the commands for the downgrade of PHP version:

```
yum downgrade php
```

The above command will give the actions that yum will do and proceed. Also you will need to do the following

```
yum --disablerepo remi-php71 downgrade php
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, after this problem I've stuck in a few days, then today I found the question.

First thing remove php71 from system,

```
yum remove php-common php-cli mod-php
```

enable remi-php70

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
```

after that disabled the 7.1

```
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php71
```

then do

```
yum update
```

then install php 7.0.x

```
yum -y install php70u php70u-pdo php70u-mysqlnd php70u-opcache php70u-xml php70u-mcrypt php70u-gd php70u-devel php70u-mysql php70u-intl php70u-mbstring php70u-bcmath php70u-json php70u-iconv php70u-soap
```

restart apache and it's work.

I think this way is also work for downgrading from php 7 to 5

Answer (score 2):

As you have php 7.1 from remi-php71 repository, you have to switch to remi-php70 repository

```
# yum-config-manager --disable remi-php71
# yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
# yum downgrade php php-common php-....
```

P.S. php70u or php70w are from other repositories, please notice that mixing various repositories is a bad idea.